# gulp, "terminal mode" for node app

Tags: node.js, gulp, entry-point

I am working on a node app whose main purpose is to parse and evaluate an input string (interpreter) provided by an end user from within the browser.

However, it is a bit cucumbersome when working on the development of the interpreter to have to constantly switch back and forth between the browser and the terminal. Therefore I want to have an entry point to the interpreter directly from the terminal.

Currently I figured out a simple way to do this (based on node's documentation https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin):

```
gulp.task('term', function(){ 
    if(typeof process != 'undefined'){
        (function () {
            var util = require('util');
            var inputString = "";

            console.log("Instruction: provide a string followed by ctrl+d");

            process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
            process.stdin.on("readable", function(){
                var chunk = process.stdin.read();
                if (chunk) inputString += chunk;
            });

            process.stdin.on("end", function(){
                // executed on "end" signal (ctrl + d)
                console.log("here we send inputString to interpreter() -> ", inputString);
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

When running `gulp term` gulp will complete and then enter in a "terminal mode" where it is waiting for userInput. When finishing the session (ctrl+d), the input is sent to the interpreter.

When running `gulp term < inputFile.txt` the content of inputFile.txt is sent to the "end" event of process.stdin.on and the file's content is immediately sent for evaluation to my interpreter.

This scenario describes well what I mean by "terminal mode". However, I am not sure that this is the neatest way of doing so.

One problem here is for instance the "instruction line" being printed in between "starting" and "finishing" og the gulp task:

```
$gulp term

[10:08:10] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/app/gulpfile.js
[10:08:10] Starting 'term'...
provide a string followed by ctrl+d
[10:08:10] Finished 'term' after 853 μs
// now waiting for input
```

So my question is, "how to provide an efficient terminal like entry point to my node app?", is there a more Gulpish way of doing so? Any example of apps providing such a "terminal like" entry-point?

Thanks in advance for your help